# OneSignal notification being exhibit on screen

Tags: java, rest, react-native, onesignal

I would like my notification to be displayed only in the notification bar. When the application is open, it is displayed on the screen as a modal.

In the official documentation I found nothing that could help me with this. I would like to know if I should look for another section of the documentation or should I alter my app.

If that configuration are on my app, how should I alter it?

Using Java for the ms. and React-Native for the app.

Answer (score 2):

```
OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(0);
```

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk#section-set-in-app-focus-behavior